# getting column names in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I was wondering how to tell if a column with a certain name exists in a certain database table. I'm using JDBC but if it can be done with pure SQL, it's even better. The solution has to be independent of the DBMS-provider however. I guess I could do that by querying the first row of the table and getting ResultSetMetaData from it, but that assumes there is a row in a table. I would want it to work with an empty table too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ResultSetMetaData` still works, even if the table is empty...

Answer (score 14):

You can get them from `DatabaseMetaData`.

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = meta.getColumns(...);
```

Comment: Just be aware that the table name is case SENSITIVE when you're using `getColumns(null,null,tablename,null)` to get the columns for a table.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if the table is empty. [ResultSetMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) will still give you information about the types and properties of the columns in a ResultSet object.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve general information about the structure of a database with the java.sql.DatabaseMetaData interface.

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmeta = con.getMetaData();
```

call getColumns(), to get description of table columns available.