# Search every column in every table for a string in Sybase Database

Tags: sql, database, string, search, sybase

I am in charge of finding some data stored in a sybase database. This is because the schema is unknown and there is no one who knows the database structure. The names are also obscure and not relevant. All I have access to is ISQL.

Is there a query to search for this string within all the columns in every table?
Or is there a way to dump the database into a human readable format and then search the output?

Thanks.

Comment: JDBC can query tables/views/columns in a vendor independent way, using **DatabaseMetaData**. One advantage: instead of checking SQÖ types VARCHAR/CHAR/TEXT one may use java type String. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896737/getting-column-names-in-jdbc/6896765#6896765

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you can send SQL queries to your database with iSQL. If so, the database structure is itself stored in a table called sysobjects, which you can query using something like

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U'
```

To get a list of tables, for example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429898/from-a-sybase-database-how-i-can-get-table-description-field-names-and-types) provides a lot of useful information on how to get list of tables etc. from a sybase database.

From there, you should be able to construct a query that recursively queries all user tables.

Answer (score 0):

@Astrum,

Please confirm I correctly understand your situation:

- you have some given search string "ABCXYZ"
- you want to search for it in *any* column of *any* table
- you don't know the names of your columns or tables

If so, then best you BCP out your data then grep through them.

```
$ isql << EOF > tables.txt
select name from sysobjects
where type = 'U'
go
EOF

$ for table in `cat tables.txt`
do
bcp $table out $table.dat -c
done

$ grep 'ABCXYZ' *.dat
```

The advantage of this strategy is that you now have a copy of all your data on hand for doing further analysis.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
select object_name(id) as tableName
from syscolumns
where name = "XXX"
```

this query will return all the table(s) that has a column "XXX". You can also use like operation as name like "%XXX%".